# Can someone explain the meaning of android studio memory dump?

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-dump, android-profiler

I know the "retained size", it mean "Total size of memory being retained due to all instances of this class", but what does the rectangle behind the number mean?
[image]

Comment: [bar plot](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=bar+plot&iax=images&ia=images)

Answer (score 1):

The rectangle behind the number represents the contribution of this row to the sum of all rows combined. The longer the rectangle is, the larger is the value. So the rectangles across the rows present a histogram of these values. Hope it helps.